# How can we use average total time if a job to determine time of components?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistical-significance, sample, weights

Imagine a scenario where there are tasks (called jobs) made of many smaller tasks (called assemblies). Each assembly has an average time to completion, and the job time to completion is a sum of the time to completion of its assemblies. Each assembly is independent of the others in terms of time to completion (more on this later). Assemblies are of seven types (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) with their own average time to completion.

Assuming that I have a sheet that contains a list of jobs, their time to completion and how many assemblies were used on each, how would I estimate the average time to complete each assembly? Assume that each job may be made of a many assembly types, for example job one may be composed of assembly a,d,e and job 2 composed of assembly d,b,c, and so forth, and we don't have data on the amount of time it took to complete each assembly.
Here is an example:

[image: List of jobs, time to job completion and which assemblies were used]

Now I should be able to simply take the average time for a job, divide by its number of assemblies  and get an average time to complete each task. Then, as I accumulate a large number of jobs, I can divide the number of each assembly used with the sum of the average assembly completion time in jobs they appear in, like so:

[image]

But this doesn't work where some assemblies are often completed together and have significantly different average time to completion. For example, you can see from my initial data that D,F and G are often (but not always) completed together; but I know from experience that task F should take more than 3 times longer than D.

The question is: how do I correctly weight a huge sample (<1000) job times  based on assembly frequency to get a correct average time to complete each assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this in a straightforward linear regression problem. You have seven unknown assembly completion times $\beta_1$ through $\beta_7$, and observed relationships between the presence of your assemblies and total job duration, plus some error or variance. For instance, the first line of your table can be translated into

$$ \beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_4+\beta_6+\beta_7+\epsilon_1 = 72, $$

where $\epsilon_1$ is the error for the first job.

You can actually collect all your jobs into one big $n\times 7$ "design matrix" $X$ (which will look just like columns A through G in your table) and set up your problem vectorially:

$$ X\beta +\epsilon = y, $$

where $y$ contains the observed total job times in one large vector.

If each assembly is only done either not at all or once, $X$ will only have zero and one entries. But the concept works equally well if some assemblies happen more than once for a job - just put in the number of times the assembly happened.

Given the design matrix $X$ and your observations $y$, you can immediately get [least squares estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) of the assembly time vector $\beta$. Any statistical software can do this, your sample is nowhere too large. (In a pinch, MS Excel should also be able to do this.)

Just be careful to exclude the leading column of ones that are often silently added to the design matrix. For instance, in R you would write something like `lm(y~X-1)`, where the `-1` tells R not to use this "intercept" column.

This would make sense as a simple first approach. You may want to get fancier by investigating the noise term $\epsilon$ more deepy. For instance, you might hypothesize that the noise or variance increases with the number of assemblies involved. There are weighted versions of least squares estimation that can address issues like this, but to be honest, I would assume this initial approach to get you 95% of the way.

Comment: Worked fantastic, thank you!